# Slow Query when performing partial field matches between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for any tips on how I can speed up this query. What I have are 2 tables with barcodes, one barcode has extra data from the other dataset, and I need to know which ones match. For example table A has barcode **ABC12345678YZ**, and in table B there is a barcode **1234567**, the ABC and YZ are just prefixes and suffixes that get dropped (they aren't fixed length or anything so I cannot just trim them off), in this case they are actually the same scan.

The logic is straightforward enough, however since table A has 292,000 records and B has 182,000 it is taking horribly long to run. I ran it all night with CPU spiked to 100% no luck. This is a VM with 10 cores and 150GB of ram, running SQL Server 2019.

```sql
SELECT a.Id
into __MatchingScans
FROM  AllScans AS a INNER JOIN
merged AS b ON b.[Piece Barcode] LIKE '%' + a.Barcode + '%'
```

Comment: Is there a deadlock on the table? Have you got an open transaction (not committed or rolled back)? What are the data types of the barcodes? This should not be taking long.

Comment: In table B you only know the middle part and have no idea what the complete barcode is (because the prefix and suffix is not generated based on that middle part). Correct? But in table A where you have the complet barcode, can you say which part of it is the base part used in table B? In your example it's just the digits in the center. Maybe it is not that simple in reality, but is there a rule to know the substring we are interested in?

Comment: Well, reading this again, Jonathan Willcock is right. Joining on `LIKE` is far from ideal, but to join two such rather small tables should not take long. If you told us it took ten minutes, I might have said: "well that's longer than what I expected", but all night???

Comment: Slight detour....sql server 2012 is no longer supported. It doesn't affect the question at hand but you do need to get your upgrade plan sorted out.

Comment: Reading the question again, shouldn't you be using `on a.barcode like '%' + b.[Piece Barcode] + '%'`?

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking to add a computed column to your table `merged` which doesn't have the prefix and suffix on the barcode value; then you can `INDEX` that and likely have a much faster query.

Comment: Jonathan, forgive my ignorance on this part, but how can I check. It is single user DB with only my query running, so I cannot think of why it would be locked. Is there a command to check? And my bad on the version it is actually 2019.

Comment: Try using `sp_who2`?

Comment: There are no locks or uncommitted trans(I found a post on how to check). However I do think Jonathan was correct that the logic is flipped. Still wouldn't explain it running endlessly.

Comment: Are you sure that your table AllScans does not have empty barcodes or something.  In that case you would have LIKE '%%' , so basically a CROSS JOIN.

Comment: You can check (in another session) what the result is so far: SELECT * FROM __MatchingScans (nolock)

Comment: As Thorsten asked in the second comment, is the "base" barcode numbers and ther prefix letters? Because if you can tell the prefix from the base we can give you a solution, please let us know!

Comment: Honestly, an indexed computed column is really the way to go. On a little test server your query with some test data hadn't finished after 10 minutes, but when you add an indexed computed column for the `barcode` in `merged` it ran in < 1s in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rAem4VXi).

Comment: Too address some of the responses, there is no way to extract/compute just the barcode data part, the prefix and suffix aren't fixed in anyway, sometimes it is text sometimes alpha, no delimiters. Larnu are you saying just add an index, because I'm trying to follow the fiddle but the abc prefix was just an example it could be anything as the prefix or suffix. Just not sure how to compute the indexed column.

Comment: Have you confirmed that in both tables barcode is not an empty string? Otherwise you do potentially have a cartesian (cross) join. This would blow the server's mind! Actually a single character could be almost as bad as an empty string. Please check `min(len(barcode))` on both tables

Comment: Johnathan, that seems to have did the trick. I removed any barcodes with a len < 6 because in my case those are invalid anyway. I also cleaned up the duplicates. And although it is still running it is finally returning data as before it wasn't. I'm not sure how StackOverflow works, but if you give that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

1. If possible try to get distinct barcodes from both tables if there are a lot of duplicates. This would minimize the number of rows you join together
2. if there's some sort of pattern to the pre-postfixes, it might be possible to clean them up. For example prefixes are characters and barcode is numbers only.
3. Probably the reason it times out is that it takes too much memory to build the combination of both tables or that it uses too many CPUs. Try to set OPTION (MAXDOP 5) to limit number of thread workers.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real rhyme or reason to the extra data. It seems to be CPU bound as memory isn't capping out but CPU instantly jumps to 100% and stays there for hours, so how would limiting the cores to 5 instead of 10 help? I understand it may keep from bogging down the whole server, but that isn't a big deal being an after hours operation.

Comment: If server uses too many cores, sometimes a lot of time is wasted on synchronizing the workers rather than performing actual work. So for such queries it can sometimes improve results to minimize number of CPUs to use. If you check sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats for your processid, these kind of problems usually creep up in form of very high CXPACKET waits

Comment: Good luck. Poor server still have to join together 182,000 x 292,000 pretty much by a cross join here. :(